# Searching through very large files with php to extract a block very efficiently

Tags: php, performance, file-io

I've been having a major headache lately with parsing metadata from video files, and found part of the problem is a disregard of various standards (or at least differences in interepretation) by video-production software vendors (and other reasons).

As a result I need to be able scan through very large video (and image) files, of various formats, containers and codecs, and dig out the metadata. I've already got FFMpeg, ExifTool Imagick and Exiv2 each to handle different types of metadata in various filetypes and been through various other options to fill some other gaps (please don't suggest libraries or other tools, I've tried them all :)).

Now I'm down to scanning the large files (upto 2GB each) for an XMP block (which is commonly written to movie files by Adobe suite and some other software). I've written a function to do it, but I'm concerned it could be improved.

```
function extractBlockReverse($file, $searchStart, $searchEnd)
{
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if($handle)
    {
        $startLen = strlen($searchStart);
        $endLen = strlen($searchEnd);

        for($pos = 0, 
                $output = '', 
                $length = 0, 
                $finished = false, 
                $target = '';
            $length < 10000 && 
                !$finished && 
                fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) !== -1; 
            $pos--)
        {
            $currChar = fgetc($handle);
            if(!empty($output))
            {
                $output = $currChar . $output;
                $length++;

                $target = $currChar . substr($target, 0, $startLen - 1);
                $finished = ($target == $searchStart);
            }
            else
            {
                $target = $currChar . substr($target, 0, $endLen - 1);
                if($target == $searchEnd)
                {
                    $output = $target;
                    $length = $length + $endLen;
                    $target = '';
                }
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
        return $output;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('not found file');
    }
    return false;
}

echo extractBlockReverse("very_large_video_file.mov", 
    '<x:xmpmeta', 
    '</x:xmpmeta>');
```

At the moment it's 'ok' but I'd really like to get the most out of php here without crippling my server so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this (or tweaks to the code which would improve it) as this approach seems a bit over the top for something as simple as finding a couple of strings and pulling out anything between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the fast string searching algorithms - like [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
 or [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) in order to find the positions of the start and end tags, and then read all the data between them.

You should measure their performance though, as with such small search patterns it might turn out that the constant of the chosen algorithm is not good enough for it to be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

With files this big, I think that the most important optimization would be to NOT search the string everywhere. I don't believe that a video or image will ever have a XML block smack in the middle - or if it has, it will likely be garbage.

Okay, it IS possible - TIFF can do this, and JPEG too, and PNG; so why not video formats? But in real world applications, loose-format metadata such as XMP are usually stored last. More rarely, they are stored near the beginning of the file, but that's less common.

Also, I think that most XMP blocks will not have sizes too great (even if Adobe routinely pads them in order to be able to "almost always" quickly update them in-place).

So my first attempt would be to extract the first, say, 100 Kb and last 100 Kb of information from the file. Then scan these two blocks for "

If the search does not succeed, you will still be able to run the exhaustive search, but if it succeeds it will return in one ten-thousandth of the time. Conversely, even if this "trick" only succeeded one time in one thousand, it would still be worthwhile.

Comment: 'Usually' XMP is stored near the end of large files (so I'm reading from the end), but not even different versions of the same software seem to keep to that, so they can sometimes be found in odd places (particularly if the head contains an embedded preview or other binary data). I think one of the next steps will be to try and tweak the code to add a 'zone of consideration' to focus on the start and the end, then only search the middle if neccesary. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but searching "backwards" is significantly expensive even on buffered streams -- most implementation will blithely throw away their buffers on seeking backwards (True, there's still the underlying OS buffering, which ameliorates the situation). Much better to jump directly 100K or 200K before the end, and read forward the whole block. Heavier on memory usage, but not all that much. Then again, I guess it's all a matter of trying -- between OS, buffers, disk cache, and so on, there're too many factors to give one definite answer.